# preg match email and name from to

Tags: regex, match, pcre

i want to find name and email from following formats (also if you know any other format that been getting use in mail application for sending emails, please tell in comment :))

how can i know name and email for following format strings (its one string and can be in any following format):

```
 - jon435@hotmail.com
 - james jon435@hotmail.com
 - "James Jordan" <jon435@hotmail.com> (gmail format)
 - janne - jon44@hotmail.com (possible format)
```

Comment: The third and forth formats that you described don't exist as far as I know.  Gmail extracts the name for display purposes, but the name is stored with the address in the following standard format: "firstname surname <name@domain.tld>"  You should probably only look for that format and just plain addresses.

Comment: oh sorry, i did added the <, but i think it removed it, sence i didnt add that inside code tag

Comment: You should get a proper RFC822 (et. seq.) parser, and not rely on just the small number of email formats you've seen.  No reason not to be "net friendly" on this.

Comment: any links randal or any help on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is straightforward, at least for the email portion. The rest can be special-cased away.

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

[Proof I'm not insane.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have those strings, it is going to require more work than a simple regular expression. For instance, your first example doesn't include the full name, it is only the e-mail, thus, you would have to use the Microsoft Live ID API to retrieve that information...and that turns out to be really hard.

What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: im making an invitation app, for importing contacts and sending them invitation for the site.

Comment: importing contacts from what?